# Unable to write to external storage after integrating Hockey sdk even after adding permission request module

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to add permission related to external storage using permission model but not able to get the popup for external storage permission. I have added even more permissions. This one was not working only.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far !!!

Comment: make sure your app have target sdk version >= 23 and and you are testing above android api 23 and above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hockey library recently started to not use the permission for using external storage. Therefore they added a check for maxSdkVersion to 18. You can see this in Merged Manifest file.
 All you need to do is add this permission for accessing external storage.

```
 <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
```

Comment: It might not have any explanation but it's the only the that worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case helps move  CrashManager.register(this); to code performs after grant own permisson. It helped me.

Comment: you should call registration after grantted write permission

Answer (score 0):

According to the Hockeyapp's documentation: "If you are using HockeySDK-Android 5.0.0 and later, the SDK limits the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to devices with api level 18 or lower." If android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is necessary for your app to function, you can override Hockey's implicit merged manifest permission setting by appending 'tools:node="replace"'. This allows your app's manifest to override Hockeyapp's permission. Reference: https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android/hockeyapp-for-android-sdk#permissions-advanced

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:node="replace"/>
```